# Парсер Selenium. Как оптимизировать Chrome и Chromedriver?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

использую Selenium и Chrome Driver, чтобы открывать две вкладки до нужной страницы и столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:

Во время прохода по страницам Chrome что-то сохраняет в озу и упорно не хочет это удалять, до того момента, пока не заполнит её полностью и не поломается(зависнет).

Я думал, что это кэш, что браузер запоминает все открытые за сессию вкладки и т.д. и т.п. поэтому чистил всё что только возможно очистить: кэш, куки, историю(пробовал и во время работы парсера); включал Disable cache и другие функции в Network, обнулял массивы, хранящие вкладки в коде, но ничего не помогло. Озу как заполнялась, так и продолжает. В итоге я уперся в +-250 записей в бд. А нужно спарсить Несколько тысяч.

Что делать?

[image: скрин Диспетчера задач 1]
[image: скрин Диспетчера задач 2]
[image: скрин Диспетчера задач 3]

Comment: Пробовал запускать браузер в headless mode? Пробовал отключать логи?

Comment: Я не очень шарю, но селениум и хром драйвер вроде подразумевают работу именно в headless chrome. Под отключением логов вы имеете в виду preserve log в inspect? Если да, то пробовал:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Путём наблюдений стало понятно, что ОЗУ заполняется из-за
Chromedriver.exe

Решением стало создание счетчика с перезапуском драйвера каждые n записей.
Пример моего счетчика:

```
i = -1
for d in url:
    driver.get(d['href'])
    href_stat = d.get('href')
    i += 1
    print (i)

    if i == 20:
        driver.quit()
        chromedriver = "C:/Projects/parser/chromedriver"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
        driver.get(d['href'])
        i = 0
```